# Finding an angle which satisfies two equations

Tags: trigonometry

I'd like to prove the following: Given any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, not both zero, there exists $c \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ such that $\sin c = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ and $\cos c = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$. I'm trying to use as little geometry as possible, and appeal to the formal properties of sine and cosine.

So far what I have is this:

> By hypothesis, $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \neq 0$. Thus, $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 +b^2}} \in [-1,1]$,
>   and it follows from the intermediate value theorem
>   that there exists some $c \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ such
>   that $\sin c = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$. But $\sin^2 c + \cos^2 c = 1$
>   , which implies
>
> $$  \cos^2 c = 1 - \frac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac{b^2}{a^2 + b^2}. $$
>
> It follows that $\cos c = \pm \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$.

Of course, this is almost what I want, but is there a way for me to rule out the negative case?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: $c$ must be in $[-\pi,\pi]$ or $b$ must be $\ge 0$.

Comment: $\cos$ is non-negative on $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I see why $b$ must be greater than 0, but I'm not sure how to proceed if I allow $c \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Do you think you could help me out with that?

Comment: I'd rather say "It follows that $\cos c = \pm \frac{|b|}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$" then we select the appropriate sign for $\cos c_1$ by letting ($c_1=\pi-c$ if $a\ge 0$ or $c_1=-\pi-c$ if $a<0$) if $b<0$ and $c_1=c$ otherwise. $c$ remains in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ with $\cos c\ge 0$. $c_1$ will be the desired angle. It is more simple to consider unit circle :)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you so much for your helpful comments!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a trick question.

It is impossible to prove such a claim because it is not true. If you really want to prove the truthness of such a claim I'd start with the claim that for any real numbers $a$ and $b$ there exists an angle $\theta$ such that $\cos{\theta} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$, $\sin{\theta} = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$, and $ \theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$

A case where the claim you're trying to prove does not hold is when $a=-1$ and $b=0$